# Spring-Integration-Kafka BOM

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

quick question. Currently spring-integration-kafka doesn't appear to be a part of the BOM for spring-integration, so that when specifying dependencies in gradle it's an oddball out for having to declare the version (when using the spring dependencies plugin).

Is there a BOM somewhere I should be importing? No big deal if not.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.5.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        // Need something here for spring-integration-kafka?
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:3.0.1.RELEASE"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not such an inclusion into any existing BOM.

We are still in doubts to merge it into the Core project or not: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3966.

However that might be a good argument to include it into the Spring Boot dependency management. Feel free to raise an issue against Spring Boot. 
One of the reason might like like there is a strong compatibility between Spring Integration Kafka & Spring Kafka and Apache Kafka per se. See the table in the end of the page: https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/

Comment: Adding spring-integration-kafka to the spring-integration-bom, while it's still an extension, defeats the whole reason for having it as an extension, which is mainly because it has a faster release cycle than spring-integration itself. That said, things seem to be stabilizing from a Kafka perspective now, so we can definitely consider moving it to core in 5.1 or 5.2.